# angular 2 router.navigate do not navigate to the right url

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I'm using an login and want to redirect to the saved url state.

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
return this.http.post('/api/authenticate', JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }))
  .map((response: Response) => {
    // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
    let user = response.json();
    if (user && user.token) {
      // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
      this.alertService.success("Login success", true);
      this.location.back();
    }
  });
```

}

This is the login which i observe here

```
login() {
this.loading = true;
this.authService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
  .subscribe(() => {
      this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
    },
    error => {
      this.alertService.error(error);
      this.loading = false;
    });
```

}

The problem: `this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);` do not navigate to to the returnUrl. But when i'm debugging there is the correct url saved.

Comment: Can you give us the definition of **this.returnUrl** please ?

Comment: `this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/admin';`

Comment: If you pass a array as argument for router.navigate. Your fragments should not be prefixed slash. Try to pass a string instead or remove slashs.

Comment: But the url in the browser gives me `http://localhost:4200/admin/login?returnUrl=%2Fadmin` so the returnUrl gave me the right one i think. Or do i have to transform `%2F` into a `/`?

Comment: `decodeURIComponent('%2Fadmin')` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

Comment: In debugger `returnUrl = /admin/users` as example. So i think i have to remove the first `/`.